# How to get total items count in specific index of List<object>?

Tags: java, android, json

I have used retrofit 2 for request data from API and have some JSON response format like below.

```
{
     result: [
        {
           kolom1: "PI 0",
           kolom2: "PV 0",
           kolom3: "TP 0",
           kolom4: "10",
           kolom5: "20",
           kolom6: "30",
           kolom7: "FK 0",
           kolom8: "CA 0"
        },
        {
           kolom1: "PI 1",
           kolom2: "PV 1",
           kolom3: "TP 1",
           kolom4: "10",
           kolom5: "20",
    }
```

This is my model class.

```
public class DetailKPIModel {
    private String kolom1, kolom2, kolom3, kolom4, kolom5, kolom6, kolom7, kolom8;

    public String getKolom1() {
        return kolom1;
    }
}
```

This is my response model class.

```
public class ResponseModel {
    private List<DetailKPIModel> resultDetail;

    public List<DetailKPIModel> getResultDetail() {
        return resultDetail;
    }
}
```

This is my onResponse method.

```
@Override
public void onResponse(Call<ResponseModel> call, Response<ResponseModel> response) {
   //get total items in result index 0
}
```

I want to know size of

> response.body().getResultDetail().get(0)

How to get total of items in every index of result?
My expected results are like these:

- Total result index 0 is 8
- Total result index 1 is 5

Comment: add some method to `DetailKPIModel`, which will check the number of non-null fields of it, and return it

Comment: Thanks for your response, I'll try it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**try this way on your model class**

```
    public class DetailKPIModel {
            private String kolom1, kolom2, kolom3, kolom4, kolom5, kolom6, kolom7, kolom8;

            public String getKolom1() {
                return kolom1;
            }

            public int getCount(String value){
                int count =0;
                if(value.equalsIgnoreCase(kolom1.substring(kolom1.length()-1))){
                    count++;
                }
                .
                .
                .

                if(value.equalsIgnoreCase(kolom8.substring(kolom8.length()-1))){
                    count++;
                }
return count;
            }
        }
```

**pass the value 0 or 1 in getCount() method**